# CNTK: c# sample for parallel request processing and Clone() method performance

Tags: cntk

In the c# sample for parallel request processing 
 https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/zhouwang/cseval-example-clone/Examples/Evaluation/CNTKLibraryCSEvalCPUOnlyExamples/CNTKLibraryCSEvalExamples.cs

how expensive is it to call rootFunc.Clone(ParameterCloningMethod.Share) ?
We are currently calling it per request we receive in our service but it would be worth knowing if it is something not advisable to be doing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Clone() with parameter sharing is not expensive regardign memory overhead, since all cloned instances share the model's parameters, e.g. weights. Regarding latency, it should also be quite low, as it only creates some in-memory network description data structure. Of course, if you use a pool to manage all cloned instances, you will get better performance.